# Could not initialize class org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonObjectInspectorFactory

Tags: java, json, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load `json` data into hive table using `JSONSERDE` but i am facing this problem

FAILED: `Execution Error`,

> return code 1 from `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask`. Could not initialize class org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonObjectInspectorFactory

**QUERY:**

```
    create  table tip(type string,
        text string,
        business_id string,
        user_id string,
        date DATE,
        likes int)
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("mapping.date"="date")
        STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Please help..

Comment: You have posted two questions on the same topic within 2hours. Which problem you are facing now ?

Comment: I have solved that problem.The problem was with SERDE jar.Then i used org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde.